# pizza project thick or thin

Tags: java

Hi I'm making pizza project and want user to pick only 1 base so once he says yes to thin there will be no question for the thick base.

```
 System.out.print("\nDo you want thick base?");
    input = keyboard.nextLine();
    choice = input.charAt(0);
    if (choice == 'y'){
        pizza.setPizzaBase(new PizzaBase("thick"));
    }

    //Thin base 
    System.out.print("\nDo you want thin base?");
    input = keyboard.nextLine();
    choice = input.charAt(0);
    if (choice == 'y') {
        pizza.setPizzaBase(new PizzaBase("thin"));
    }
```

Comment: Might it be better to extract the keyboard listening logic into it's own class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A nice and simple else statement!

```
 System.out.print("\nDo you want thick base?");
    input = keyboard.nextLine();
    choice = input.charAt(0);
    if (choice == 'y'){
        pizza.setPizzaBase(new PizzaBase("thick"));
    } else {
        //Thin base 
        System.out.print("\nDo you want thin base?");
        input = keyboard.nextLine();
        choice = input.charAt(0);
        if (choice == 'y') {
            pizza.setPizzaBase(new PizzaBase("thin"));
        }     
    }
```

Comment: What if the user answers `N` in both cases? Will he get all the toppings without a base? That would be a mess...

Comment: Maybe the user is wheat intolerant? :)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar possibly a second else? `} else { System.out.print("Way too messy without a base - bye"); }`