# pizza project, vegetarian option

Tags: java

I'm making a project with online pizza system and got a problem.  I want java to say that the pizza will be vegetarian or not. I got ham topping in my toppings list, so if users takes pizza with ham it should say that it is not vegetarian otherwise it should say that pizza is vegetarian. I do not know how to do that, can anybody show me example ?

```
 System.out.println("Order Confirmation: ");

    System.out.println(pizza.getPizzaBase().getName() + " crust pizza");
    for(PizzaTopping pizzaTopping: pizza.getPizzaToppings()){
        System.out.println("1 x " + pizzaTopping.getName());
    }
```

Comment: You forgot the part where you ask a question.

Comment: Think about doing this in real life. If you were going through a list of pizza toppings, what would you do with each item to see if the entire pizza was vegetarian? Also, do you want to do this for just a "ham" option, or for any non-vegetarian item?

Comment: The word "that" in the sentence "I do not know how to do that" is very broad. What part specifically are you unsure how to do?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel This is probably related to [pizza project thick or thin](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20524316/1281433), which also didn't have a clear question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the topping type in the for loop. This code is simplified - instead of the test for "ham" typically one would write a isVegetarianTopping() method which would contain the list of non-veggie toppings.

```
System.out.println("Order Confirmation: ");    
System.out.println(pizza.getPizzaBase().getName() + " crust pizza");
boolean vegetarian = true;
for(PizzaTopping pizzaTopping: pizza.getPizzaToppings()){
    if (pizzaTopping.getName().equals("Ham") || pizzaTopping.getName().equals("ham"))
        vegetarian = false;
    System.out.println("1 x " + pizzaTopping.getName());
}
if (vegetarian)
     System.out.println("Vegetarian")
 else
     System.out.println("Not Vegetarian")
```

Comment: That second `if` statement doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you have an interface called "Meat" that all non-vegetarian option classes implement? Then you can all all the toppings and iterate to check whether there is a non-veg option? Or you can just do it while adding it to the pizza? You only need to know that there is only 1.

Comment: Some sort of `enum` "toppingType" field would also work in a similar way too (depending on the exact use-case and requirements).

Answer (score 0):

```
    System.out.println("Order Confirmation: ");

    System.out.println(pizza.getPizzaBase().getName() + " crust pizza");
    for(PizzaTopping pizzaTopping: pizza.getPizzaToppings()){
        if (pizzaTopping.getName().toLowerCase().equals("ham") {
            System.out.prinln("Vegitarian pizza");
        }
        System.out.println("1 x " + pizzaTopping.getName());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Order Confirmation: ");

System.out.println(pizza.getPizzaBase().getName() + " crust pizza");
for(PizzaTopping pizzaTopping: pizza.getPizzaToppings()){
    if (pizzaTopping.getName().toLowerCase().equals("ham") {
        System.out.prinln("Not vegitarian pizza");
    }
    else System.out.prinln("Vegitarian pizza");
    System.out.println("1 x " + pizzaTopping.getName());
}
```

Comment: it prints out if is vegetarian for each topping, i just want to say if the pizza is vegetarian at the end or not